How to call multiple custom hooks fetching data depending on previous data inside a custom hook itself?
To get certain data, I need to call multiple custom hooks, all of which are making api requests to get some data, then after each call, I need to use gotten data to pass to the next custom hook to get the next data.

If I put the all the calls except the first one into a useEffect hook and the needed data into the dependency array this will give me an error as I cant call custom hooks conditionally inside an effect.
Or should I call the first one inside a useEffect, then storing result in state and then just have a simple if statement, so if there is state, call the other hooks

const useSomeCustomData = ({ids}) => {
  const { data: firstData } = useFirstData({
    ids: ids,
  });
  const investmentIds = firstData?.investments.map(
    (investment) => investment?.id
  );
  //next one depending on previously gotten investmentIds
  const { data: secondData } = useSecondData({
    investmentId: investmentIds ? investmentIds : undefined,
  });
  const start = secondData?.products?.map((product) => {
    return product.date;
  })[0];
   //next one depending on previously gotten "start" from secondData
  const { data: thirdData } =
    useThirdData({
      startDate: start,
    });
}


Hooks get called during render, no matter what, and you can’t wrap them in if’s, ever (and expect things to consistently and logically work). The logic you put inside the hook will dictate precisely what it does when called with a certain value. For example, when calling useThirdData with a value of undefined for startDate, you can choose to do, or not do whatever you want.

Do you only have the api requests as hooks, or can you extract the request part out into (async) functions?

Hello, if you want to simplify your code when fetching data you can use a third party library TanstackQuery.
Then you can use the enabled attributes to wait on the previous data !

@Adam Jenkins Can you explain what you mean - do you mean inside the useThirdData I can decide what to do?

@Caleth Yes api requests as hooks

This is not a hooks problem, its a design pattern issue.
If you have a bunch of changed queries which need to fetch some data, wrap those in an async function and use that queryFn in a useEffect.
Chaining of queries is just a .then chain on first fetch.
You can have multiple states wired up to your queryFn and have setState calls in each step.
Instead of using your hook multiple times, move the query chain inside that hook, and use it once.

As built-in hooks, custom hooks are also part of a component’s body. It takes part in rendering a component. Therefore it is illegal to invoke a built-in or a custom hook in the handler of the useEffect hook. As we know, the handler of this hook runs only after rendering the component.
One of the most elementary custom hooks which wraps a network fetch may be written in the pattern as “feed the url and get the data out”. The following custom hook works on that basis.
// note: error handling has not been included here for brevity
function useData(url) {
   const [data, setData] = useState(null);
     useEffect(() => {
     if (url) {
       let ignore = false;
       fetch(url)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((json) => {
           if (!ignore) {
             setData(json);
           }
         });
       return () => {
         ignore = true;
       };
     }
   }, [url]);
  return data;
}

When the above custom hook is used to retrieve a set of related data, we can chain the hooks as the below code does. It means the output of one hook is fed to another and so on. The custom hook useSomeCustomData below chains the three elementary data hooks and get the final data. The most important aspect in the below code is the “reactive value” url used in the “dependency array” of the three hooks, whenever the url will change with respect to the query strings, then the chain of hooks will automatically restart to execute.
App.js updated on 2-Oct-24 11am IST
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(Math.random());
  const someCustomData = useSomeCustomData(query);
  return (
    <>
      {someCustomData ? someCustomData : 'Loading..'}
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
       
          setQuery(null); // to reset the display
          setTimeout(() => setQuery((query) => Math.random()), 0); // made async to avoid batching
        }}
      >
        Fetch again
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

const useSomeCustomData = (query) => {
  const firstData = useData(
    query ? `/api/firstdata?queryfield=${query}` : null
  );
  const secondData = useData(
    firstData ? `/api/seconddata?queryfield=${firstData}` : null
  );
  const thirdData = useData(
    secondData ? `/api/thirddata?queryfield=${secondData}` : null
  );

  return thirdData;
};

function useData(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url) {
      const timer = setTimeout(
        () => setData(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1)),
        2000
      );
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    } else {
      setData(null);
    }
  }, [url]);
  return data;
}

Test run
On initial load

After the mocked async calls

On clicking Fetch again button

After the mocked async calls

